# How should the code structure of a distribution look like?

Tags: 8, distributions, installation-profiles

I'm making a distribution and so far it consists of only one module which holds the whole code.

Since D8 is now fully OOP and has autoloader and other stuff I was wondering how should the structure of the distribution look like.

1. The profile should be empty and the module should hold all logic
2. The profile should hold all logic and act as a module and no additional module is required
3. The profile should be empty and the one large module should be split into smaller modules

The modules holding all the logic is big but it holds only the core functionality so splitting it into smaller modules would be good only for easier orientation in files but the rewriting that it would take does not compensate the change.

On the other hand moving everything into profile actually sounds good. I don't see any point in having the profile encapsulate the module just because.. And rewriting the code in this case would be easy.

And finally: the current model - empty profile with one big module. I have no problem with this other than having the empty profile sitting on top if it all.

What do you think?

Comment: I don't think this question should be considered as too broad. The list I gave is just what I came up with but I it's not meant to be a "pick one".